# How to respond to jQuery Validation remote?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

Looked at multiple SO questions and the manual, but can't find it out. When I have

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({ 
    rules: {
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
      remote: "check-email.php"
    }
  }
});
```

How should my `check-email.php` respond? I already tried `echo "true"`, `echo true`, `echo {error: true}`, but it's not giving the right error message.

**EDIT**

I currently have my php set up as:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='".$_POST['email']."'") or die (mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($query)!=0){
echo json_encode(false);
}else{
echo json_encode(true);
}
```

However, it's always returning true...

Comment: What exactly have you done to troubleshoot that your database query is returning anything?

Comment: I just found out that $_POST['email'] is empty. So something is going wrong in making the ajax request.

Comment: By default, the request is a `GET`.  Again, you have to [read the documentation where this is clearly spelled out](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/).

Comment: Thank you, I'm sorry for not reading it properly. One other thing that goes wrong now: when I get a false first with email address 1, then a true with email address 2 and then a false with email address 3, the message is: 'email address 1 is not available'. So somehow, the message is not refreshed. That is not covered in the doc.

Comment: I can't make any sense at all out of your last comment.  I have no idea what you're talking about... how I am supposed to know if those email addresses are in your database and what the response is supposed to be?  Please update your OP with a clear explanation.

Comment: If you want an exact error message, then you need to follow the documentation... so instead of returning `false`... return a string containing the error message.

Comment: Thank you, that works. Is it possible to have multiple remotes in one form? I'm using the exact same code for the username, but that one is not working.

Comment: Yes, there are no known issues with using the remote method on more than one field in the same form.   Since I solved your issue as posted, please "accept" my answer below.  Then feel free to post a new question for your new issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> How should my `check-email.php` respond? I already tried `echo "true"`,
>   `echo true`, `echo {error: true}`, but it's not giving the right error
>   message.

That's because `true` will not trigger an error message... it is the opposite response.

- `true` is the proper response for when it's valid (no error message).
- If the response is `false`, `null`, `undefined`, or a string (error message) the field is evaluated as invalid.

**Quote Title:**

> How to respond to jQuery Validation remote?

[You should read the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/):

> The serverside resource is called via jQuery.ajax (XMLHttpRequest) and
>   gets a key/value pair corresponding to the name of the validated
>   element and its value as a GET parameter. **The response** is evaluated as
>   JSON and **must be `true` for *valid* elements**, and can be **any `false`,
>   `undefined` or `null` for *invalid* elements**, using the default message; or
>   a string, eg. "That name is already taken, try peter123 instead" to
>   display as the error message.

---

**EDIT**:

As per edits and comments...

- OP is using `$_POST['email']` in his PHP.  However, the documentation above states that the `remote` method uses `GET` by default.
- If you want a customized error message, then you need to follow the documentation above... so within your PHP, instead of returning `false`... construct the message and return it within a string.

Comment: Thanks, but I also tried false.

I currently have:
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='".$_POST['email']."'") or die (mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($query)!=0){
 echo json_encode(false);
}else{
 echo json_encode(true);
}

but now it's always giving true...

Comment: @user2859066, if it's always giving `true` then there is something wrong with your PHP, not your jQuery.  It's impossible for me to troubleshoot something on your server or see what's in your database... so what have you tried so far to verify that your PHP & database logic is correct?