# Remote validation for multiple fields with jQuery validation

Tags: php, jquery, validation

I'm using the jQuery validation plugin to check if the user excists in my SQL database. I want to check the credentials in checkCredentials.php. My script **does** check if an email or password is filled in but it **does not** check if the credentials do exist in my database. Anybody who can tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

This is my **form**:

```
            <form action="php/login.php" method="post" id="loginForm" class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Wachtwoord" />
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-block" type="submit" name="login" value="Login">Login</button>
            </form>
```

And this is my **script**:

```
    $( "#loginForm" ).validate( {
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        password: {
            required: true,
            remote: {
                url: "php/checkCredentials.php",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    email: function () {
                        return $("#email").val();
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    },
    messages: {
        email: {
            required: "Vul alsjeblieft een e-mail adres in"
        },
        password: {
            required: "Vul alsjeblieft een wachtwoord in",
            remote: "E-mail of wachtwoord onjuist"
        },
    },
```

And here is my PHP file **checkCredentials**.php

```
<?php
require 'database-connection.php';

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['email']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['password']);

$query = "SELECT user_email, user_password FROM table_users WHERE user_email = '$email' AND user_password = '$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
    echo 'true';
}
else
{
    echo 'false';
}
?>
```

Comment: You don't hash your passwords?

Comment: @MattS this is only for testing if it works now

Comment: Open your browser's console i.e, in chrome press F12. And go the the network and then check whether your validation is hitting the correct url path or not. If yes, do some debugging there with an `exit()` to see back-end response run-time. It will help you to resolve the issue I believe

Comment: Check if `$_REQUEST['password']` is available in your PHP file...

Comment: It does hit the correct url path, i'm gonna debug now to see what's the problem. Thanks for your answer @hmd

Comment: I actually had two errors. I forgot that mysqli_real_escape_string needs two parameters, that problem is solved now. But $email and $password got a undefined index error. I'm trying to solve that error now.

Comment: I looked into the documentation as someone said in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/20051659/7603806. I changed $_REQUEST to $_POST but still get an undefined index error..

Comment: Undefined index error on password or email or both? Look at line code.

Comment: Both at email and password, I also tried get, post and request @alvarofvr

Comment: When I remove type: "post" from my script and use get in checkCredentials.php it works, but I don't think it's smart to send login credentials through the url

Comment: Your code in my enviroment work. The code first of edit. Try to add var_dump($_REQUEST); die(); after first line code of your PHP file

Comment: And so open the console (F12) and type the password and look at Network

Comment: Yeah it works now! Thanks for your help everyone appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code to this and it's working now:

**Form:**

```
    <form action="php/login.php" method="post" id="loginForm" class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Wachtwoord" />
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-block" type="submit" name="login" value="Login">Login</button>
                </form>
```

**Script:**

```
    $( "#loginForm" ).validate( {
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                remote: {
                    url: "php/checkCredentials.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        email: function () {
                            return $("#email").val();
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        },
        messages: {
            email: {
                required: "Vul alsjeblieft een e-mail adres in"
            },
            password: {
                required: "Vul alsjeblieft een wachtwoord in",
                remote: "E-mail of wachtwoord onjuist"
            },
        },
        errorElement: "em",
        errorPlacement: function ( error, element ) {
            error.addClass( "help-block" );


            element.parents( ".col-sm-5" ).addClass( "has-feedback" );

            if ( element.prop( "type" ) === "checkbox" ) {
                error.insertAfter( element.parent( "label" ) );
            } else {
                error.insertAfter( element );
            }

            if ( !element.next( "span" )[ 0 ] ) {
                $( "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>" ).insertAfter( element );
            }
        },
        success: function ( label, element ) {
            if ( !$( element ).next( "span" )[ 0 ] ) {
                $( "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback'></span>" ).insertAfter( $( element ) );
            }
        },
        highlight: function ( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
            $( element ).parents( ".col-sm-5" ).addClass( "has-error" ).removeClass( "has-success" );
            $( element ).next( "span" ).addClass( "glyphicon-remove" ).removeClass( "glyphicon-ok" );
        },
        unhighlight: function ( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
            $( element ).parents( ".col-sm-5" ).addClass( "has-success" ).removeClass( "has-error" );
            $( element ).next( "span" ).addClass( "glyphicon-ok" ).removeClass( "glyphicon-remove" );
        }
    } );

</script>
```

**checkCredentials.php:**

```
<?php
require 'database-connection.php';

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

$query = "SELECT user_email, user_password FROM table_users WHERE user_email = '$email' AND user_password = '$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    echo 'true';
}
else
{
    echo 'false';
}
?>
```